# epsg_operations.properties

Tags: coordinate-system, java, geotools

I am trying to include an epsg_operations.properties definition into my Java /Geotools Project. I thought it would be the best solution to include the gsb-File for a GRID-Transformation. So I inserted the following into my epsg_operations.properties File:

```
25832,31467 = PARAM_MT [ "NTv2" , PARAMETER [ "Transformation XXX" ,  "XXX.gsb" ]]
```

I added the epsg_operations.properties File as well as the gsb-File to my resources root, als well as the org.geotools.referencing.epsg package within the resources.

Nothing helped so far. Any other suggestions are very welcome.

Comment: does https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/configuration/crshandling/coordtransforms.html#add-grid-shift-transform-files help?

Comment: I am not using geoserver here. But I used that documentation and created a epsg_operations.properties file just like the one used there. The problem is, that my java code isnt reading this properties file. I cant get a MathTransformation object based on the defined operations.

Comment: take a look at how the geoserver code does it?

Comment: @aleho did you make any progress with the properties file?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add to `epsg.properties` to add a grid shift transform to a GeoTools application. Simply create a directory `org/geotools/referencing/factory/gridshift` in your projects `resources` folder and put the `gsb` file into it.

If you want to check it's working then this code will show you which transforms are available between two CRS.

```
CoordinateReferenceSystem src = CRS.decode("EPSG:27700");
  CoordinateReferenceSystem target = CRS.decode("EPSG:4326");
  Map<String, AbstractCoordinateOperation> grid_trans = CRS.getTransforms(src, target);
  for (String code : grid_trans.keySet()) {
    System.out.println(code + " " + grid_trans.get(code).getAccuracy());
  }
```

By default GeoTools will pick the one with the lowest accuracy figure (which may or may not be what you want so you can over rule it an provide a specific transform either from a list as above or by the `MathTransform.findTransform(CRS, CRS, transformCode)` method.